# Resume Restore issue after internet goes offline

Tags: iphone, ios, restore

How do I resume a restore from iCloud on a new iPhone 8? The restore was halted when our Internet network went (scheduled) offline.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I think you have to start over.  What have you tried?  Please see [ask] for tips on asking questions.

Comment: I agree with @fsb that you probably have to start over.  However, how often does your Internet go offline?  How much time are you allocated when the Internet is up?

Comment: Goes offline at midnight every day for all. Comes back on at 6:00 a.m.

Comment: @DWilliams Why?

Answer (score 1):

It should resume right away wen the internet is back online! This happened to me and it just resumed right away! If your worried about it, go to a public place and do the restore! It should only take about 10-15 minutes!